# Столкнулся с вот такой проблемой: Error:Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined for module 'pogoda'

Tags: java, groovy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке вывода в консоль выпадает такая ошибка. Подскажите, как это можно исправить ?

Comment: ...............

Answer (score 1):

Надо просто добавить поддержку groovy в ваш проект - вот, описание как это сделать. Даже с картинкой:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450683/errorcannot-compile-groovy-files-no-groovy-library-is-defined-for-module-mypr

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант уже видел, во время создания этого вопроса. Но не разобрался с ним. Не понял что добавлять. В итоге проект удалил и создал новый, теперь ошибка эта пропала.